# How can I retrieve phone numbers from Google Directory API?

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm using Directory API with PHP to retrieve all users. 
A response for a user who has a phone number added looks like this:

> Google_Service_Directory_User Object ( [collection_key:protected] =>
>   nonEditableAliases [addresses] => [agreedToTerms] => 1 [aliases] =>
>   [changePasswordAtNextLogin] => [creationTime] =>
>   2016-11-29T14:21:30.000Z [customSchemas] => [customerId] => 1234
>   [deletionTime] => [emails] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [address] =>
>   test@companymail.com [primary] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [address] =>
>   test@companymail.com ) ) [etag] => "tagg" [externalIds] =>
>   [hashFunction] => [id] => 12344 [ims] => [includeInGlobalAddressList]
>   => 1 [ipWhitelisted] => [isAdmin] => [isDelegatedAdmin] => 1 [isMailboxSetup] => 1 [kind] => admin#directory#user [lastLoginTime]
>   => 2016-12-12T10:13:31.000Z [nameType:protected] => Google_Service_Directory_UserName [nameDataType:protected] =>
>   [nonEditableAliases] => Array ( [0] =>
>   test@companymail.com.test-google-a.com [1] => test@companymail.com )
>   [notes] => [orgUnitPath] => / [organizations] => [password] =>
>   **[phones] =>** [primaryEmail] => test@companymail.com [relations] => [suspended] => [suspensionReason] => [thumbnailPhotoEtag] =>
>   [thumbnailPhotoUrl] => [websites] =>
>   [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array ( ) [modelData:protected]
>   => Array ( [name] => Array ( [givenName] => TestNAme [familyName] => TestNAme [fullName] => TestNAme TestNAme ) ) [processed:protected] =>
>   Array ( ) )

The phone number was set 5 days ago (it's there), but as you can see the "phones" array is empty.

This is how I use the API:

```
$directory_service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
$params = array('domain' => $domain);
$results = $directory_service->users->listUsers($params);
$users = $results->getUsers();
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. Do I need to enable any settings? 
How can I get users' phone numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The user removed their phone number?

Comment: No, I'm testing for my user so I am 100% sure that the phone number is added.

Comment: and does the user you are authenticating with have access to see the user you are checking?

Comment: Yes, the API lets me see all users and their details (name, emails) but their phones are always empty even though I set some phone numbers. The result for a single user it's shown below.

Comment: Assuming they are all part of $domain then I am out of ideas sorry.

Comment: Could it be possible that the phone numbers are stored under a custom schema? or any other attribute?

Comment: @Morfinismo
I don't think so, here explains how a user response looks like: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users

Comment: I know, I am familiar with it. Is the phone number also not shown when testing it in the "try it" section here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list?

Comment: @Morfinismo, yes, it is not shown there.

Comment: Why don´t you try https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get using the `projection` value as `full` and see if the phone number appears in any other field?

Comment: Tried it, no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have added phone numbers for the domain contact but in your own contacts data. These will display 'merged' with the domain contact details in the Contacts UI and appear correct to you. They won't be visible to others though or be stored in the domain data.

Do this for testing:

1. Pick a domain user account and add a phone number for them using the admin console Users UI. Admin console > Users > (select User) > Account > Contact information > Edit > Add a phone > Click Update User.
2. To confirm your addition, use Try this API here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get and just enter your user account name from 1 (email address) in userKey, for viewType select `admin_view` and click Execute.

You should see the phone data in the JSON returned. Once you can do this you can retest your PHP code.